# Can't create an Availability Group with Powershell when instance uses non-standard port

Tags: sql-server-2012, availability-groups, powershell

I am trying to create an Always On Availability Group with PowerShell, something I have done many times before but am hitting an issue now that I am using non-standard ports for the SQL Instance

I generally use a slightly modified version of [this script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Create-an-AlwaysOn-4f450340)

But I get an error saying that the current instance SERVER\INSTANCE,Port must be added to the availability group before it can be created. Now obviously that is the value I pass in at the top of the script

```
$SqlServerPrimName = "SERVER\INSTANCE,Port"
```

Which is then used to create a SMO object

```
$SqlServerPrim = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($SqlServerPrimName)
```

And then added to the Availability Group here

```
$AvailabilityGroup.AvailabilityReplicas.Add($PrimaryReplica)
```

But it obviously is not working!

I notice also that if you try and call `$SQLServerPrim` it comes back empty for InstanceName even though the object is correctly loaded with other values

Creating an Availability Group through the GUI works

Using the `New-SQLAvailability*` Cmdlets have the same error

Any idea what I need to change in the code to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Change `$SqlServerPrimName = "SERVER\INSTANCE,Port"` to `$SqlServerPrimName = "SERVER\INSTANCE"` and change the port for the instance afterwards.

```
$ComputerName = gc env:computername
$SqlServerPrimName = "SERVER\INSTANCE"
$SQLServerPort = 1433
$wmi = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer") $computerName
$wmi.ServerInstances["$SqlServerPrimName"].ServerProtocols["Tcp"].IPAddresses["IPAll"].IPAddressProperties["TcpPort"].value = "$portNumber"
$wmi.ServerInstances["$SqlServerPrimName"].ServerProtocols["Tcp"].IPAddresses["IPAll"].IPAddressProperties["TcpDynamicPorts"].value = [System.String]::Empty
#We need to commit the changes by calling the Alter method
$wmi.ServerInstances["$SqlServerPrimName"].ServerProtocols["Tcp"].Alter()
```